# nohup : redirecting stderr to stdout in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have [Project](https://github.com/nava45/flipkart-scraper/archive/master.zip) that have various dependency I install it on MAC and its running good .

but the same project when i am trying to Run on ubuntu it gives error :

**nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout in ubuntu**

for running that project i have to run **./start.sh** file .

the commands in start.sh

```
nohup python2.7 redis_worker.py >> worker.out &
sleep 1
nohup python2.7 app.py >> recv.out &
echo "Visit the url: http://127.0.0.1:8802/"
echo "http://127.0.0.1:8802/"
```

then it gives out put

```
ekodev@ezp:~/Documents/flipkart-scraper-master$ ./start.sh
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
Visit the url: http://127.0.0.1:8802/
http://127.0.0.1:8802/
ekodev@ezp:~/Documents/flipkart-scraper-master$ nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
```

can any body tell me whats the main problem is ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `2>&1` at the end right before the `&`

```
nohup python2.7 redis_worker.py >> worker.out 2>&1 &
```